# Count occurences of number in list of lists

Tags: counting

I have a nested list of numbers, something like satisfied = {{1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 5,,8, 6}, ..., {5, 6, 1}} and I want to count the number of occurences of 1 in each list. I know there is 1000 of them.

I have tried

```
Do[Count[satisfied[[i]], 1], {i, 1000}]
```

since this works for one chosen list

```
Count[satisfied[[1]], 1]
```

Comment: To work with lists, refer to [`List Manipulation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListManipulation.html)

Comment: `Cases[yourList, 1, Infinity] // Length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use a loop like this in Mathematica. Use the `Count` function and just map it. You do not need to know the length of the list either.

```
lis = {{1, 5, 6, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 5, 8, 6}, {5, 6, 1}}
Count[#, 1] & /@ lis
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many other ways to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this

Comment: Very nice.  In addition, using the operator form of **Count**:   `Count[1]/@lis`

Comment: @user1066 that is good also. I myself have not looked at operator forms so I do not know much about it. I should look at these one day. I know there are at least 10 different ways to do the same thing in Mathematica, so it is a matter of finding the best method to use.